Gabriel's theorem for complex analytic spaces
Let $X,Y$ be noetherian schemes over $\mathbb{C}$.
Then, it is known that
$$
\text{Coh}(X) \simeq \text{Coh}(Y) \Rightarrow X \simeq Y,
$$
by P. Gabriel(1962).
Are there some results in the case of analytic spaces ?
I.e., Are there some results about the following question?
Question 
Let  $X,Y$ be compact analytic spaces.
$$
\text{Coh}(X) \simeq \text{Coh}(Y) \Rightarrow X \simeq Y \ ?
$$
Any comments are welcome !
Thank you.
Edit 1 
In the case of the categories of twisted sheaves, Gabriel’s theorem is proved (B. Antiea, A.Perego).
Edit 2 
After Denis commented, I found a paper by Verbitsky.
In Theorem 1.2 of the paper, a counter example of my question can be founded.
So, the following question may be more suitable.
Question 2 
Let $X,Y$ be compact analytic spaces.
$$
\text{QCoh}(X) \simeq \text{QCoh}(Y) \Rightarrow X \simeq Y ?
$$
In the case of noetherian schemes (and qs schemes by M.Brandenburg, A.L.Rosenberg) and the case (not only noetherian but also qcqs schemes) of Edit 1, Question 2 is solved (the claim holds).
According to a recent preprint by H. Liu, it is proved that $\text{QCoh}(X)$ for a complex analytic space $X$ is an abelian category.

I think that if you take a quotient of $\Bbb C^n$ by a very general lattice, then the category of coherent sheaves on this complex torus would consist only of flat bundles and skyscrapers, and full subcategories of those two kinds of objects would be semisimple. Consequently, there's little chance to distinguish them from their categories of coherent sheaves.

Thank you. I have found a paper by M. Verbitsky "Coherent sheaves on generic compact tori". In this paper, We can find a counter example (Theorem1.2) of my question.

About your question 2: good definition of a quasicoherent sheaf on an analytic space does not exist. The reason is that rings of regular functions on affine opens are not noetherian, and therefore modules locally of finite presentation do not form an abelian category. There are a few workarounds, but none are really satisfactory.

Thank you. Recently, H.Liu proved that $\text{QCoh}(X)$ is an abelian category for a complex analytic space $X$. You can see the preprint from the link in Edit 2.

I'm confused, I have also heard many times that quasi-coherent sheaves on complex manifolds just do not make sense, and one should instead work with e.g. Fréchet quasi-coherent sheaves, or appeal to the liquid/condensed framework. @DenisT does the preprint linked to in Edit 2 directly contradict your comment?

@Tim The fact that (naively defined) quasicoherent sheaves on a complex manifold are closed in O-mod under (co)kernels and extensions is an old folklore theorem. It does not really help much: the resulting category doesn't have limits, colimits, injectives,.. basically no good properties. Qcoh of a (totally arbitrary!) scheme is a good category because it is always a presentable (finitely presentable in qcqs case) Grothendieck category; in particular, there's a coherator functor, the right adjoint to the full embedding of Qcoh into O-mod.

Coherent sheaves form an abelian category on any ringed space whatsoever, and locally finitely presented sheaves form an abelian category on a locally coherent scheme. To make those categories equivalent, one needs to control exactness of colimits along cover refinements, which are, Indeed, exact on schemes - open Immersions of schemes are finite flat monomorphisms. The issue is a combination of not-quasicompactness and not-finiteness of open Immersions. In some sense this behaviour is dual to I-adically complete modules for infinitely generated I.
